# mass update connetion properties in msd

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, mxd, connection, msd

I would like to update the connection property in all .msd in a folder, that already have a certain connection property.
The manual process is to

- right click on the .msd,
- select "select all",
- select "replace all",
- select the layer in the local SDE fot that map,
- click add
- and ok.

Can I do this with ArcPy?

PS.  The reason for doing this is the password changed in the .sde and this is an alternative to republishing the service.

[image]

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

A msd file references a mxd file. So you should fix the datasource of mxd. I reccommend to check [this web page](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s30000004p000000) of documentation and  use `findAndReplaceWorkspacePath` for this purpose.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project_default.mxd")
mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(r"C:\Project\Connection to Default.sde", 
                                 r"C:\Project\Connection to Version1.sde")
mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Project\Project_V1.mxd")
del mxd
```

Legacy:

> Starting at ArcGIS 10.1 for Server, Map Server Definition (.msd) files
>   have been replaced with Service Definition Draft (.sddraft) and
>   Service Definition (.sd) files.

Since Service Definition Draft (.sddraft), Service Definition (.sd) and msd files are xml file, you should parse the xml and extract the mxd from the xml.